# Activator not called if plugin created by JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-kepler

I created eclipse plugin from Extenal JAR file, Like [EclipseJarToPlugin](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJarToPlugin/article.html).
Then in MANIFEST.MF I'm adding `Activator` for this plugin.

But the problem is this Activator never called. Even while creating plug-in  there is no option for Activator.

Is there is any way so that we can know when first time any Exported class of this plugin(of jar) is called.?

Comment: The Activator is only called if some other class in the plugin is used, unless you explicitly start the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

How does your Activator looks like? Try simple activator, which implements `BundleActivator` interface.

Have you checked "Activate this plug-in when one of its classes loaded" - this is a checkbox on the "Overiview" tab of your Manifest editor:

[image]

Comment: Yes I try that, activator is not being called.

Comment: THANKS. I was going awfully mad on activating an _Activator_ on a plug-in while forgetting to check the option in the E4 tools wizard. I see that checking this option adds a `Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy` line in the manifest. It seems misleading, since default activation would just be.. not lazy, but it would be _there_.